# How can I apply a macro to an entire column?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to match data from one workbook to another. I have a for loop going on, and I can't figure out how to loop through the whole column without messing up the original loop.

Please help!

This is my current code where I need to run the code on each cell I want to grab the data for:

```
Sub SKU_Match()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename)
wb.Activate

Dim sh As String
sh = wb.Worksheets(1).Name
Dim lastRow As Integer
Row1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Dim index(1 To 1000, 1 To 2) As String
Dim i As Variant, j As Integer

For i = 1 To 1000
   For j = 1 To 2
        If j = 1 Then
           index(i, j) = wb.Worksheets(sh).Cells(i, 4).Value
        ElseIf j = 2 Then
            index(i, j) = wb.Worksheets(sh).Cells(i, 10).Value
        End If
    Next j
Next i

wb.Close

For i = 1 To Row1
    If index(i, 1) = Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value 
Then
        ActiveCell.Value = index(i, 2)
    End If
Next i


End Sub
```

I've tried looping in this way, but then this will just enter the data for the active cell in all the rows without separately applying the macro to each row:

```
Sub SKU_Match()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename)
wb.Activate

Dim sh As String
sh = wb.Worksheets(1).Name
Dim lastRow As Integer
Row1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Dim index(1 To 1000, 1 To 2) As String
Dim i As Variant, j As Integer

For i = 1 To 1000
   For j = 1 To 2
        If j = 1 Then
           index(i, j) = wb.Worksheets(sh).Cells(i, 4).Value
        ElseIf j = 2 Then
            index(i, j) = wb.Worksheets(sh).Cells(i, 10).Value
        End If
    Next j
Next i

wb.Close
For k = 0 to 58
    For i = 1 To Row1
        If index(i, 1) = Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value 
    Then
             ActiveCell.Offset(k,0).Value = index(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
Next k


End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you should step back and explain what the broader goal of your macro is :)

Comment: You are not incrementing the `ActiveCell` so you are just continuously writing over whatever cell is active. You are going to want to not use the `ActiveCell` and find a way to explicitly state what range you need to loop over.  Please explain what the goal is. You are loading an array from your variable `wb`. Then you want to check that against the current book? What sheet? What columns? Help us help you.

Comment: @urdearboy I'm currently trying to automate the way I record monthly sales numbers for all my SKUs. I'm downloading the sales numbers online to workbook wb. I am loading specific data (namely SKU and sales number) from wb to array index, which will be the two columns. Then I want to match my current sheet which I record all the monthly sales data on to the array and load column 2 (which would be the sales #) to the right SKU. But because it is a monthly sale, the column I am recording the numbers on will always be changing, which is why I wanted to use ActiveCell. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If you are trying to load sales data for one month only (as you are loading two cols only) from the workbook then why looping through K? what is the variable `k` stands for? It may be monthly column but you are using it as row offset.. .

Comment: @AhmedAU I was trying to increment the ActiveCell with K, but after trying, I know that's not what I should be doing. What would be a better way of incrementing through the column?

Comment: My answer was purely  based on assumption. I could not understand how you want to structure the data. May please edit your post and provide details specific of how you want to structure the data or at least provide sample images of  Input file data and expected result

Answer (score 0):

The solution is based on assumption each value of the match found will added to the worksheet in the row corresponding to SKU and column offset will increment for each match found. Also I think there is no need to store the `wb` values in a array, It could be pickup from the `wb` directly. Even if it comes close to your goal feel free to ask.

```
Sub SKU_Match2()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename)
Dim sh As String
sh = wb.Worksheets(1).Name
Dim lastRow As Integer

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Row1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count


For i = 1 To Row1
K = 1   'Assumtion: offset column kept 0 and will be incremented for each found
    ValToMatch = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value
        For j = 1 To 1000
        MatchVal = wb.Worksheets(sh).Cells(j, 4).Value
        ValtoAdd = wb.Worksheets(sh).Cells(j, 10).Value
            If MatchVal = ValToMatch Then
            K = K + 1   'Assumtion: each value of the match found will added to the worksheet in the
            'row corresponding to SKU and column offset will increment for each match found
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, K).Value = ValtoAdd
            End If
         Next j
Next i
wb.Close False
End Sub
```